# Как вставить массив в матрицу и вывести ee?

Tags: javascript

Земля:

```js
let ground = [
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
];
```

Змея: `let snake = ['@','=','='];`

Вывод матрицы:

```js
function displayMatrix() {
  ground.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    let groundstr = item.toString();
    groundstr = groundstr.split(',').join();
    console.log(groundstr);
  })
}
```

Желаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно (нужно) вставить всё кодом, а не картинками

Comment: Мне кажется или вы это пишите на NodeJS?)

Comment: @EzioMercer Да, на node

Answer (score 0):

```
let y = 7;
let x = 7;
for( let i = 0; i< snake.length;++i) {
  ground[y][x+i] = snake[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо это:

```js
const ground = [
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '=', '=', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
];

function displayMatrix(matrix) {
  console.clear();
  
  let str = '';

  matrix.forEach(row => {
    str += row.join(' ') + '\n';
  });

  console.log(str);
}

displayMatrix(ground);
```

А ваш `let snake = ['@','=','='];` вместо символов должен хранить значения из самого массива, типа `let snake = [ground[x1][y1], ground[x2][y2], ground[x3][y3]];`

Comment: Хорошо, а если добавляется ещё один элемент то как его отображать и задать ему координаты?

Comment: @tage_off Ну, это явно не короткий вопрос) По хорошему вам наверное надо создать класс `SnikeBodyPart` - это будет родительским классом, как для головы так и для хвоста. В нём будут храниться начальные координаты при создании и будут методы обновления координат. Далее создаём ещё 2 класса `SnakeHead` и `SnakeTail`, которые будут наследоваться от `SnikeBodyPart` и в которых юудет поле для хранения отображаемого символа. И начальное значение вашего массива `snake` будет `[snakeHead, snakeTail, snakeTail]`. При поедании яблока вы просто в этот массив добавляете `new SnakeTail(x, y)`

Comment: @tage_off Теперь сама логика движения: Каждый раз перед обновлением координат у частей змеи, вы в массиве `ground` в старых координатах частей змеи вставлете знак `' '` вместо символа части змеи. Потом обновляете координаты у частей змеи, проходите по всему массиву `snake` и по новым координатам в массиве `ground` рисуете соответствующие символы змеи и рисуете новый `ground`. Надеюсь объяснил просто и доходчиво)